# How to apply a class on <li> when mouse is hovering on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I defined a CSS class "active", and want to apply this class on a **<li>** tag *only when* the mouse is hovering on it. How to do that?

Here is a Bootstrap example:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
</ul>
```

And when the mouse is hovering on any **<li>**, apply class "active" on it.

Hope CSS could provide something like this, because I want to avoid writing same plain CSS text again and again.

```
.list-group-item:hover
{
    include .active;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `:hover` but adding class is not possible with plain CSS.

Comment: `active` actually means something else in CSS ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should avoid using unnecessary javascript when you can do it simply with CSS, like everyone else pointed out already

but nonetheless jquery way would be

```
$('.list-group-item').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

first block is when the mouse is over the element, second is when it leaves it
https://jsfiddle.net/o9na7ps0/1/

Comment: Thanks. Really hope CSS could provide more support on composition of class instead using plain text. Something like  .list-group-item:hover { include .active; }

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to create a class `.active`?
you should do it this way:

```
.list-group-item:hover {
   /* body of the active class here*/
}
```

this way, you don't need to create a seperate class for the hovering.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

HTML `<li class="active list-group-item">First item</li>`

CSS `li.active:hover {...}`

Answer (score 0):

hover on every li

```
li:hover{
  background-color: #ffeeff;
}
```

hover on class list-group-item

```
.list-group-item:hover{
  background-color: #ffeeff;
}
```

hover on li with class list-group-item

```
li.list-group-item:hover{
  background-color: #ffeeff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this `.list-group-item:hover{color: white;}` to your CSS like this example https://jsfiddle.net/7sud8341/2/